# Unable to import module 'copy': /var/task/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: ELF file's phentsize not the expected size

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am following - https://github.com/christianhxc/aws-lambda-redshift-copy

When I tried to test it, I am running into error

```
Unable to import module 'copy': /var/task/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: ELF file's phentsize not the expected size
```

This is the file structure in AWS.
[image]

Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the name of your file `copy.py` . AWS is confusing it for other libraries and can't catch the name that you set on the controller.

You just need to rename your file.